# Axis ActualMaximum and Maximum don't match after zooming or padding (OxyPlot)

Tags: c#, charts, oxyplot

I have made an example project to try and fix this bug but no luck. I have made a simple WPF application with a Plot and a Button inside it. The button, when clicked, it sets the X Axis minimum to 100 and maximum to 500.
It works when I open the app, but as soon as I pan/zoom the chart it stops working.

[When debugging, you can see that the Maximum changes, but the ActualMaximum value stays the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYx3Q.png) Same goes for the Minimum and ActualMinimum.
Here is my PlotModel code and my MainWindow code. I apologize if I format anything badly, I'll try to fix it as soon as possible.

```
public class OxyPlotModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private OxyPlot.PlotModel plotModel;
        public OxyPlot.PlotModel PlotModel
        {
            get
            {
                return plotModel;
            }
            set
            {
                plotModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PlotModel");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }

public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            oxyPlotModel = new OxyPlotModel();
            oxyPlotModel.PlotModel = plotModel;
            plotView1.DataContext = oxyPlotModel;

            plotModel.Axes.Clear();

            var yAxis = new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis();
            var xAxis = new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis();
            xAxis.Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Bottom;

            plotModel.Axes.Add(yAxis);
            plotModel.Axes.Add(xAxis);

            plotModel.Axes[1].Minimum = 0;
            plotModel.Axes[1].Maximum = 700;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            plotModel.Axes[1].Minimum = 100;
            plotModel.Axes[1].Maximum = 500;
            Debug.Print(plotModel.Axes[1].MaximumPadding.ToString());
            plotModel.InvalidatePlot(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using Axis.Zoom instead of Maximum and Minimum.